# Uploading an image dynamically from one div to another in a seprate webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I've done a little bit of research on this and I can't find a clear answer or if its possible. I've been trying to load an image from a div into another div that exists on another page,which is displayed in an iframe. The reason I'm doing this is because I would like to create a dynamic image preview for a banner printing service and I want to be able to display an accurate preview of what an image would like when resized. I've been trying jQuery's ".load()" function and it runs without error yet the image is not load into the div.

```
$("#destination").load("path/path #source", function(){
        alert("Load was performed.")
            });
```

This function runs yet the image is not on the other webpage even after refreshing the iframe.

Comment: http://www.zomeoff.com/javascript-how-to-load-dynamic-contents-html-string-json-to-iframe/

Comment: Thank you I hadn't stumbled across this tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "postMessage" to pass the image url to the IFRAME and in IFRAME page capture the "massage" event and perform your operation

reffer  `http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage`

Comment: Thank you for this post Manivannan. After messing with the code I was able to get the image to load in the iframe, but what's happening now is I'm getting this"received: 10492146_683376518407247_2842178196320115123_n.jpg" in my iframe instead of the actual image itself.